# Different purposes of 的

Tags: grammar

What's the purpose of 的 in these sentences?

1. 马大为给女朋友小燕子**的**一封信
2. 奶奶问我，是不是自己来**的**医院？
3. 你有什么不懂**的**， 在百度上都可以找到答案.

Also, what does 小燕子 mean in the 1st sentence? Is it a proper noun?

Comment: 小燕子 is a person's name (or nickname)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Sentence 1: 马大为给女朋友小燕子的一封信***

的 is an **adjective marker**. The part that goes before 的 modifies the noun that goes after 的.

The literal, word-for-word translation will yield the following:

"Ma Dawei - give - girlfriend - Xiao Yanzi 的 letter".

In English, the idiomatic way of expressing this would be using a **relative clause**:

The letter that Ma Dawei gives his girlfriend Xiao Yanzi.

Think of a relative clause (in English) as an **extended adjective**, and you will get the meaning in Chinese - The {Ma-Dawei-gives-girlfriend-Xiao-Yanzi} letter.

English has something similar as well, for examples, a {God-given} talent, a {well-written} essay, etc. But when the description gets longer than a couple of words, a relative clause becomes the preferred way of expressing it.

***Sentence 3: 你有什么不懂的， 在百度上都可以找到答案.***

The function of 的 in the third sentence is similar, except here the noun 东西 (thing) is omitted because it is understood.

不懂的(东西)

The {you-do-not-know} thing is expressed as a **relative clause** in English: Things that you do not know.

***Sentence 2: 奶奶问我，是不是自己来的医院？***

This sentence is a little different. "自己来的" does not modify the noun "医院", but rather is more closely related to the (understood and omitted) subject 你.

The question "是不是自己来的医院？" seems like an **inverted sentence** to me.

Perhaps the underlying sentence is

你**是不是**自己来医院**的**？

Did you come to the hospital by yourself?

Compare:

你**是不是**朋友送来医院**的**？

Did a friend bring you to the hospital?

你**是不是**坐公車来医院**的**？

Did you come to the hospital by bus?

The 的 here is part of the 是 ... 的 expression, which gets inverted.

**Note**: The 是 ... 的 expression probably deserves a separate discussion on a different day.

Comment: I like your answers, but in this case, I'm curious, really. Are you saying: 自己来 is an adjective for 医院？What would that mean? A self arrived hospital??
奶奶问我，（你）是不是自己来的医院？
Mama asked me, (you) is not is self come 的 medicine courtyard? Maybe you could clarify??

Comment: @Pedroski I did not include sentence 2 in my answer, exactly for the reason you mentioned. I believe 2 is a little different in its structure, which I have not figured out yet.

Comment: Ditto that: I haven't figured it out yet either! I can see why Mohammad was perplexed!

Comment: I have just edited my answer with more examples, as well as added an explanation for sentence 2.

Answer (score 1):

1. 小燕子 is just a common nick name for girls.
   [马大的信]=[Mada's letter].
2. This sentence is highly simplified.
   The whole sentence should be (如果）你有什么不懂的（东西）,（你）在百度上都可以找到答案。

Comment: 1. It should be 马大为的信 Ma Dawei's letter.

Answer (score 0):

The first two "的" are "possessive particle", the third is "of".

1. 马大为给女朋友小燕子的一封信 - 马大为的信 (Ma's letter)
2. 奶奶问我，是不是自己来的医院？- 自己来的 (Came by myself)
3. 你有什么不懂的， 在百度上都可以找到答案. - 不懂的 (Does not understand of)

小燕子 (little Martin) is his girlfriend's nickname.